# java - spring validtion - disbale other validations on a field when first validation fails

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

I'm working on a java spring mvc application. I have a model and I set two validation annotation on top of a field. Here is a code sample:

```
public class MyModel{

   @NotBlank(message = "This field can not be blank")
   @NationalCode(message = "Invalid national code")
   private String name;

   ....

}
```

When I left `name` empty and submit the form, error validation array has two members:

```
name => This field can not be blank
name => Invalid national code
```

But, I don't want second line. In fact, I want to **when first validation on a field fails, all other validation on that field stop executing.** How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing here is the the grouping functionality offered by the [Bean Validation specification](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/). You need to define logical groups so that any error message generated by an annotation that belongs to the given group will only be displayed. See [section 4.4.2. Group sequence](http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-groupsequence-groupsequence) for more information.

In a nutshell define a marker interface of your own, for example, `NotBlankGroup` and add this interface class to your `@NotBlank` annotation,

```
@NotBlank(message = "This field can not be blank", groups = NotBlankGroup.class)
```

so that you will only get the message in `@NotBlank` when the `name` field value is empty.

And later if you wish to add `@NationalCode` or other custom or predefined annotations you could easily add `NotBlankGroup` to other annotations with `groups` so that they all will be evaluated as one group.